# jQuery and PHP require

Tags: php, jquery, require

I just need to know something. I have this code in jQuery:

```
$(function() {
    $("#draggable").draggable();
    var place = 0;
    var body = 0;
    $('#cables').hide();
    $(".droppable").droppable({
        drop: function(event, ui) {
            $(this).addClass("ui-state-highlight");
            if(place === 0) {
                if(this.id == "mo") {
                    place ++;
                    body ++;
                    $('#draggable').css({
                        'background-color':'#00FF00',
                    });
                    $('#draggable').text('Grafická karta');
                }
                else {
                    place++;
                    $('#draggable').css({
                        'background-color':'#FF0000 ',
                    });
                    $('#draggable').text('Grafická karta');
                }
            }
            else if (place === 1)  {
                if(this.id == "gp") {
                    place ++;
                    body ++;
                    $('#draggable').css({
                        'background-color':'#00FF00',
                    });
                    $('#draggable').text('Processor');
                }
                else{
                    place++;
                    $('#draggable').css({
                        'background-color':'#FF0000 ',
                    });
                    $('#draggable').text('Processor');
                }
            }
            else if (place === 2) {
                if(this.id == "cp") {
                    place ++;
                    body ++;
                    $('#draggable').css({
                        'background-color':'#00FF00',
                    });
                    $('#draggable').text('RAM');
                }
                else {
                    place++;
                    $('#draggable').css({
                        'background-color':'#FF0000 ',
                    });
                    $('#draggable').text('RAM');
                }
            }
            else if (place === 3) {
                if(this.id == "ra") {
                    place ++;
                    body ++;
                    $('#draggable').css({
                        'background-color':'#00FF00',
                    });
                    $('#draggable').text('HDMI');
                    $('#cables').fadeIn();
                }
                else {
                    place++;
                    $('#draggable').css({
                        'background-color':'#FF0000 ',
                    });
                    $('#draggable').text('HDMI');
                    $('#cables').fadeIn();
                }
            }
            else if (place === 4) {
                if(this.id == "hdmi") {
                    place ++;
                    body ++;
                    $('#draggable').css({
                        'background-color':'#00FF00',
                    });
                    $('#draggable').text('X');
                }
                else {
                    place++;
                    $('#draggable').css({
                        'background-color':'#FF0000 ',
                    });
                    $('#draggable').text('X');
                }
            }
        },
        over: function(event, ui) { 
        }
    });
});
```

And this is HTML5 markup:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="cs" dir="ltr">
    <head>
        <title>Hardware</title>
        <link rel='stylesheet' type='text/css' href='graph/design.css'>
        <link rel='shortcut icon' type='image/x-icon' href='favicon.ico'>
    </head>
    <body>
        <span class="display"></span>
        <section id='game'>
            <article id='draggable'>
                Základní deska
            </article>
            <article id='images'>
            <?php require('cont/kabely.php') ?>
                <table>
                    <tr>
                        <td><img src='graph/motherboard.png' id='mo' class="droppable ui-widget-header"></td>
                        <td><img src='graph/cpu.png' id='cp' class="droppable ui-widget-header"></td>
                        <td><img src='graph/gpu.png' id='gp' class="droppable ui-widget-header"></td>
                        <td><img src='graph/ram.png' id='ra' class="droppable ui-widget-header"></td>
                    </tr>
                </table>
            </article>
        </section>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/jquery.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/ui.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/cookie.js'></script>
        <script type='text/javascript' src='scripts/external.js'></script>
    </body>
</html>
```

And the external is

```
<table id='cables'>
    <tr>
        <td><img src='graph/hdmi.png' id='hdmi'></td>
        <td><img src='graph/lan.png' id='la'></td>
        <td><img src='graph/napajeci.png' id='na'></td>
        <td><img src='graph/rca-composite.png' id='rc'></td><tr>
        <td><img src='graph/vga.png' id='vg'></td>
        <td><img src='graph/usb2.png' id='u2'></td>
        <td><img src='graph/jack.png' id='ja'></td>
        <td><img src='graph/usb3.png' id='u3'></td><tr>
    </tr>
</table>
```

So where the problem is :

I am trying to make app where people will grab the sign and put it on image (jQuery ui Draggable). It works until I reach this section of code :

```
else if (place === 4) {
                if(this.id == "hdmi") {
                    place ++;
                    body ++;
                    $('#draggable').css({
                        'background-color':'#00FF00',
                    });
                    $('#draggable').text('X');
                }
                else {
                    place++;
                    $('#draggable').css({
                        'background-color':'#FF0000 ',
                    });
                    $('#draggable').text('X');
                }
            }
```

For working this I required in html external file where the files and the ids are.So they will done first 'level' and go to another so some pictures hide and some will show. They are showing well but they are not reacting on jQuery code. Can anyone help me ? They are on reacting like in jQuery if place ==1 ...
the required pictures beginning at place == 4. I hope this is understandable.

Thanks to everyone who will react.

Comment: you need to narrow your problem down, provide only codes that are really related / only those that are necessary

Answer (score 0):

```
<tr>
                    <td><img src='graph/motherboard.png' id='mo' class="droppable ui-widget-header"></td>
                    <td><img src='graph/cpu.png' id='cp' class="droppable ui-widget-header"></td>
                    <td><img src='graph/gpu.png' id='gp' class="droppable ui-widget-header"></td>
                    <td><img src='graph/ram.png' id='ra' class="droppable ui-widget-header"></td>
                </tr>
```

You have only 4 items instead of 5. So the `place == 4` will not work